# delete gap between Charts in Plotly

Tags: plot, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I config the chart's size in shiny but still have blank area between charts

they show like old area before config height&width

[image]

this is my code

```
plot1_reactive <- eventReactive(input$submit_but,{
      xaxis <- list(
                    tickformat = "%-d/%-m/%Y",
                    type='category'
                    )
      yaxis <- list(title = input$sel_par1)
      r <- plot_ly(mydata,x=date,y = a , type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers'
                   , width = 950, height = 200,line = list(shape = "linear"))%>%
      layout(xaxis = xaxis, yaxis = yaxis) 

    })
    plot2_reactive <- eventReactive(input$submit_but,{
      xaxis <- list(
                    tickformat = "%-d/%-m/%Y",
                    type='category')
      yaxis <- list(title = input$sel_par2)
      r <- plot_ly(mydata,x=date,y = b , type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers'
                   , width = 950, height = 200,line = list(shape = "linear"))%>%
        layout(autosize = F,xaxis = xaxis, yaxis = yaxis)  
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You'll need to set the `height` argument of `plotlyOutput` (UI) instead of the one in your `plot_ly` call (server). Otherwise the default of 400px will be applied.

Please see the following **reproducible** example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("p1Out", height = "200px"),
  plotlyOutput("p2Out", height = "200px"),
  plotlyOutput("p3Out", height = "200px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$p3Out <- output$p2Out <- output$p1Out <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(y=1:10, type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]